# Unable to make database connection using python adodbapi library

Tags: python, adodbapi

I am trying to make SQL Server database connection using python library `adodbapi` and  [latest](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56730) `OLEDB` provider using below code-

```
import adodbapi
import configparser

def try_connection():    
    _SERVER_NAME = "SERVERNAME"
    _DATABASE = "TESTDB"
    _USERNAME = "TERSTUSER"
    _PASSWORD = "TESTPWD"  

    conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source={0};Database={1};UID={2};PWD={3};".format(_SERVER_NAME,_DATABASE,_USERNAME,_PASSWORD))
    cursor = conn.cursor()

print( try_connection() )
```

But, I am unable to make connection. I am getting below huge trace error which I am unable to figure out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 97, in make_COM_connecter
    c = Dispatch('ADODB.Connection') #connect _after_ CoIninialize v2.1.1 adamvan
NameError: name 'Dispatch' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 116, in connect
    co.connect(kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 266, in connect
    self.connector = connection_maker()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 99, in make_COM_connecter
    raise api.InterfaceError ("Windows COM Error: Dispatch('ADODB.Connection') failed.")
adodbapi.apibase.InterfaceError: Windows COM Error: Dispatch('ADODB.Connection') failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestAdodb.py", line 41, in <module>
    print( try_connection() )
  File "TestAdodb.py", line 18, in try_connection
    conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source={0};Database={1};UID={2};PWD={3};".format(_SERVER_NAME,_DATABASE,_USERNAME,_PASSWORD))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line 120, in connect
    raise api.OperationalError(e, message)
adodbapi.apibase.OperationalError: (InterfaceError("Windows COM Error: Dispatch('ADODB.Connection') failed.",), 'Error opening connection to "PROVIDER=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=SERVERNAME;Database=TESTDB;UID=TERSTUSER;PWD=TESTPWD;"')
```

Please can anyone let me know what is wrong/missing in my connection string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting this from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/adodbapi/),

> Prerequisites:
>
> - C Python 2.7 or 3.5 or higher and pywin32 (Mark Hammond's python for windows extensions.) or Iron Python 2.7 or higher. (works in IPy2.0
>     for all data types except BUFFER)
>
> Installation:
>
> - (C-Python on Windows): Install pywin32 ("pip install pywin32") which includes adodbapi.
> - (IronPython on Windows): Download adodbapi from http://sf.net/projects/adodbapi. Unpack the zip. Open a command window
>     as an administrator. CD to the folder containing the unzipped files.
>     Run "setup.py install" using the IronPython of your choice.

Have you installed all the prerequisites for the `adodbapi` library ?

I was able to reproduce the error if I didn't have the `pywin32` library installed.

Install `pywin32` library using the command below :

```
pip install pywin32
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for help!